# How to retrieve all the paragraph in the specified particullar page using C#(4.0) and Open Xml Sdk(2.0)?

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, openxml-sdk

We are developing C#.Net(4.0) Windows Form Based Application with the use of Open Xml Sdk(2.0) for manipulating MS-WORD Files.Now i want to get the all the paragraphs in particular page.The user prompted for getting particular page no of the word file to get the all the paragraphs inside the user selected page number. How i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a quick look at the underlying XML it doesn't look like there is an attribute on the paragraph element that will tell you which page it will appear on.  The best suggestion I can give you is to have some placeholder text at the top and bottom of each page.  Then search for the a certain instance of the placeholder text based on which page the user specifies. Once you have a starting point you could retrieve all paragraphs between the two placeholder paragraph elements.

For example, if a user enters in page two, you would search for the third instance of a paragraph that contains this placeholder text and then retrieve all paragraphs until you reach the next instance of the placeholder text.  I know this isn't ideal, but its one workaround I could think of that might be feasible.